# JSF 2.2: Configure available Locales outside faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

Currently i have a section in my `faces-config.xml` such as follows:

```
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en_GB</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>de_DE</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
```

This is working as intended.

The problem is, i have to be able to define these Locales whithout touching the faces-config.xml in my war. The idea is having e.g. a config File on the resource Path defining all the available Locales.

I already tried an [programatic approach](http://memorynotfound.com/jsf-2-remove-faces-config-xml-programmatic-configuration/) as well as using a second faces-config.xml in the META-INF of another module i have access to and defining an specific file on the ressource path which should be merged according to this [article](http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.de/2007/01/using-multiple-faces-configxml-files-in.html). The second file in each case contained the above section in a valid faces-config.xml format. Both without any effect (neither errors nor any change in the behaviour)

Is there any nice way to do this without touching the original faces-config?

I am able to change the ear module and to access ressources programatically in any location. Unfortunately adjusting the `faces-config.xml` in the .war is no option.

Comment: @Kukeltje: unfortunately the answers do not help me. But the question actually seems to be very similar. I already resolve all the ressources with my own logic, i only hoped to leave the handling of browser accepted languages to the myfaces implementation

Comment: The problem is, that we want to give the user a choice between using the browser language and his own settings. Therefore we have to somehow handle the locales sent by the browser. Unfortunately the only wy doing this using Faces is by defining the locale-config. Otherwise we have to extract them from the request by ourselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misconception here as far as I can see. There is no need to configure anything in the `locale-config` if you use custom resolvers/resource bundles/whatever and have otherwise full control over things.

If you look at the answer in [Add Resource Bundles Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825442/add-resource-bundles-programmatically), you see the OmniFaces [`Faces.getLocale()`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.3/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/FacesLocal.java#L380) is used to pass a locale to the resourceBundle

```
Locale userLocale = Faces.getLocale();
ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("msgs", userLocale);
```

So what is effectively done is pass a programmatically chosen locale to it, not automagically using something that is configured in the `locale-config`.

The fact the IN `Faces.getLocale()` some code is present to use the `locale-config` is to make sure it can be used when people have something configured in `locale-config`, so it behaves as expected in plain normal JSF. In line 16 it retreives the locale send in the request by the user. In line 18 it checks this against the `supported-locale` (can be left out in a custom implementation!!!) and if no match, use the `default-locale` (can  be left out to, as can line 7-12)

```
1   /**
2     * {@inheritDoc}
3     * @see Faces#getLocale()
4     */
5   public static Locale getLocale(FacesContext context) {
6       Locale locale = null;
7       UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
8
9       // Prefer the locale set in the view.
10      if (viewRoot != null) {
11          locale = viewRoot.getLocale();
12      }
13
14      // Then the client preferred locale.
15      if (locale == null) {
16          Locale clientLocale = context.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
17
18          if (getSupportedLocales(context).contains(clientLocale)) {
19              locale = clientLocale;
20          }
21      }
22
23      // Then the JSF default locale.
24      if (locale == null) {
25          locale = context.getApplication().getDefaultLocale();
26      }
27
28      // Finally the system default locale.
29      if (locale == null) {
30          locale = Locale.getDefault();
31      }
32
33      return locale;
34  }
```

So this code can be totally tweaked to your liking, including first checking if the user has configured a locale of preference in your application and otherwise using the locale send by the browser IF supported.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i am going for (another) programatically approach completely bypassing Faces and setting the locale based on user settings and the request similar to your example

Comment: I had hoped to let faces handle the browser languages, but after short evaluation it turns out to be easier to simply decide myself

Comment: You are welcome, hope you get it working. What is 'faces/Faces' for you? The omnifaces util class or something else?

Comment: oh, sry. I did not think of mentioning that. I meant the JSF Implementation in our AS. Until now we simply called `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()` which in combination with the right `face-config.xml` provided me with the Locale JSF decided on based on the request.